# MapSelectionChangedEvent.Subscribe in VB

Tags: vb.net, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have seen multiple examples in C# like this:
...

```
MapSelectionChangedEvent.Subscribe(OnSelectionChanged);

private void OnSelectionChanged(MapSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
```

...

When I try to implement in VB.Net like this:
...

```
Dim subscriptionToken = Events.MapSelectionChangedEvent.Subscribe(OnSelectionChanged)

Private Async Sub OnSelectionChanged(ByVal args As Events.MapSelectionChangedEventArgs)
```

...
I get an error that says:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'args' of 'Private Sub
> OnMapSelectionChanged(args As MapSelectionChangedEventArgs)'